# How to apply a gradient function in python?

Tags: python, statistics, gradient

I'm searching for an implementation of the [matlab gradient function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gradient.html) in python. An example output of the is illustrated below.

The way I use it in Matlab is:

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('img.png'));
[dx,dy] = gradient(img);
```

[image]

How do I solve this problem? Is there any library or package for it?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [Numpy.gradient](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)

I found it via google searching for "Python scipy gradient"